# MongoDB: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: mongodb

There are at least two other posts with this exact problem ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309575/mongodb-service-failed-with-result-exit-code), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63643548/mongodb-active-failed-result-exit-code)). Answers on both questions haven't proved successful, so I decided to post with more information.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.6:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I installed MongoDB following the instructions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), taking care to select the version corresponding to my OS:

```
$ mongod --version
db version v5.0.5
Build Info: {
    "version": "5.0.5",
    "gitVersion": "d65fd89df3fc039b5c55933c0f71d647a54510ae",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "ubuntu1804",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

When I try starting MongoDB, I receive the following error:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mongodb
Job for mongodb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mongodb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I try the first suggestion but it doesn't prove helpful:

```
$ systemctl status mongodb.service
● mongodb.service - LSB: An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mongodb; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-01-18 15:56:17 PST; 1h 19min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 19071 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mongodb start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 6332 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 18 15:56:16 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: An object/document-oriented database...
Jan 18 15:56:16 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 mongodb[19071]:  * Starting database mongodb
Jan 18 15:56:17 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 mongodb[19071]:    ...fail!
Jan 18 15:56:17 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 18 15:56:17 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 18 15:56:17 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: An object/document-oriented database.
```

I try the second suggestions, and this is the resulting output:

```
$ journalctl -xe
Jan 18 17:16:06 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:06:941] info: [RTM] (TT141UC80) Processed 1 file_deleted event(s) over 0.00ms
Jan 18 17:16:06 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:06:941] info: [RTM] (TMTJNTNMQ) Processed 1 file_deleted event(s) over 0.00ms
Jan 18 17:16:06 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:06:941] info: [RTM] (T020XA65T3P) Processed 1 file_deleted event(s) over 0.00ms
Jan 18 17:16:08 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:08:457] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.00ms
Jan 18 17:16:10 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:10:673] info: [API-Q] (T2BRHD5EC) noversion-1642554970.664 Flannel users/info called with reason: flannel-call:users/info
Jan 18 17:16:10 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:10:673] info: [API-Q] (T2BRHD5EC) noversion-1642554970.664 Flannel users/info is ENQUEUED
Jan 18 17:16:10 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:10:692] info: [API-Q] (T2BRHD5EC) noversion-1642554970.664 Flannel users/info is ACTIVE
Jan 18 17:16:10 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:10:786] info: [API-Q] (T2BRHD5EC) noversion-1642554970.664 Flannel users/info is RESOLVED
Jan 18 17:16:12 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:12:201] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:16:13 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:13:599] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:16:16 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:16:718] info: [RTM] (E01044K0LBZ) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:16:18 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:18:673] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.00ms
Jan 18 17:16:39 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:39:717] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:16:42 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:42:063] info: [RTM] (E01044K0LBZ) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:16:43 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:43:524] info: [RTM] (T2BRHD5EC) Processed 1 presence_change event(s) over 5.80ms
Jan 18 17:16:44 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:44:009] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:16:44 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:44:527] info: [RTM] (T2BRHD5EC) Processed 1 presence_change event(s) over 6.20ms
Jan 18 17:16:48 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:48:111] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:16:50 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:50:396] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:16:51 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:51:324] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:16:51 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:51:695] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:16:51 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:51:696] info: [RTM] Setting a timeout of 92 ms to process more rtm events
Jan 18 17:16:52 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:52:663] info: [RTM] Waited 92 ms, processing more rtm events now
Jan 18 17:16:52 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:52:664] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 3 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.20ms
Jan 18 17:16:54 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:54:654] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:16:55 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:55:624] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.00ms
Jan 18 17:16:57 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:57:330] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:16:58 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:16:58:550] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:17:01 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 CRON[23583]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 18 17:17:01 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 CRON[23584]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 18 17:17:01 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 CRON[23583]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan 18 17:17:11 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:17:11:968] info: [RTM] (E01044K0LBZ) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.00ms
Jan 18 17:17:12 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:17:12:477] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.10ms
Jan 18 17:17:19 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:17:19:551] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.00ms
Jan 18 17:17:23 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 sudo[23632]:    rylan : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rylan/Documents/physics-benchmarking-neurips2021/experiments/dominoes_redyellow_pilot ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start 
Jan 18 17:17:23 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 sudo[23632]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 18 17:17:23 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: An object/document-oriented database...
-- Subject: Unit mongodb.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mongodb.service has begun starting up.
Jan 18 17:17:23 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 mongodb[23648]:  * Starting database mongodb
Jan 18 17:17:24 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 mongodb[23648]:    ...fail!
Jan 18 17:17:24 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 18 17:17:24 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 18 17:17:24 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: An object/document-oriented database.
-- Subject: Unit mongodb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mongodb.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jan 18 17:17:24 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 sudo[23632]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 18 17:17:24 rylan-ThinkPad-E590 slack.desktop[14549]: [01/18/22, 17:17:24:675] info: [RTM] (E7SAV7LAD) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 0.00ms
lines 1011-1066/1066 (END)
```

How do I get MongoDB to run?

None of the suggestions at the other SO posts have helped.

Edit: A friend suggested looking at the MongoDB log and I found:

```
"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-18T15:51:35.538-08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":989}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-18T15:51:35.538-08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

I investigated further and people suggested that I need to change the owner and group of the `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` file. I tried this and the error remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

For those that are wondering how a purge happens instead of a remove I used the following to ensure correct removal.

> sudo apt purge package name

in our instance specifically

> sudo apt purge mongodb-org

or

> sudo apt purge mongodb-server

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has a similar problem, purging and reinstalling worked. I don't know what I did differently the second time around, I'm afraid.